# Porque é que os contínuos são "contínuos"?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica

Refiro-me aos funcionários auxiliares. Em Portugal conhecemo-los sobretudo das escolas e universidades [(Priberam 9)](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/cont%C3%ADnuo), onde fazem tudo o que não é docência nem administração; no Brasil executam todo o tipo de tarefas adjuvantes em escritórios [(Aulete 9)](http://www.aulete.com.br/cont%C3%ADnuo).

Mas por que carga de água têm eles esse nome? O Houaiss só me diz que a palavra vem do latim *continuus,a,um*, e que o sentido ‘funcionário’ é anterior 1982. Pergunto-me se terão trocado os algarismos e queriam dizer 1892. Já no 1890 Fialho de Almeida os mencionava n’*Os Gatos* (4ª edição, 2.º volume, 1921, p. 147; ênfase minha):

> Imagine-se que genero d’educadores elles [prefeitos em colégios internos] seriam, vindos dos regimentos da guarnição de Lisboa, ou recrutados entre os **continuos** e os porteiros d’escriptorio despedidos!

Portanto o que eu quero saber é: quando é que aparece e donde vem este uso da palavra?

Comment: Jacinto, no Brasil o contínuo corresponde ao "office-boy" e os dois termos são usados, embora um contínuo possa ter 40 ou 50 anos de idade.  De um  modo geral os contínuos fazem de tudo o que é serviço braçal (trocar uma lâmpada, mover um computador de lugar, etc) e serviço externo para uma empresa.  Já o auxiliar de escritório costuma fazer seu serviço sentado a uma escrivaninha, escrevendo ou teclando em um computador.

Comment: @Centaurus "Auxiliar de escritório" é um termo guarda-chuva para facilitar o trabalho do departamento de recursos humanos. Muitos auxiliares de escritório são sim contínuos, fazendo serviços como entrega de correspondências, operação de fotocopiadoras, pagamentos de contas, entre outros.

Comment: @RamonMelo    Entre o que deveriam ser as atribuições de um profissional e o que ele realmente faz há, por vezes, uma grande distância.  Auxiliar de escritório não é um termo guarda-chuva.  Talvez você se refira a "auxiliar de serviços gerais".  Esse sim é um termo genérico e o indivíduo é designado para fazer qualquer coisa que uma pessoa normal, com pouca instrução, saiba fazer (varrer, trocar lâmpadas, tirar o pó, jogar o lixo fora, trazer material do almoxarifado, e até mesmo algum serviço externo.)  São atribuições semelhantes às do contínuo ou do office-boy.

Comment: De uma forma simplificada, no organograma das grandes empresas constam as funções "auxiliar", "auxiliar de escritório ou escriturário", "chefe de seção", "chefe de serviço", chefe de setor, chefe de divisão, chefe de departamento, gerente regional, gerente geral, diretoria.  O auxiliar" é o "contínuo" ou "office-boy".  Já o "auxiliar de escritório" tem atribuições semelhantes ao do escriturário, mas é um degrau abaixo.

Comment: @Centaurus De fato. Uma busca nos classificados de empregos mostrou atribuições diferentes das que eu imaginava a princípio. _Mea culpa_.

Comment: @Centaurus Eu estava a pensar precisamente nesse tipo de tarefas, baseado no que diz o Aulete; foi isso que quis dizer com *auxiliar* (executa tarefas secundárias necessárias à boa execução das principais); não sabia que isso ia colidir com o título oficial doutro tipo de funcionários.

Comment: Contínuo neste aspecto vem de continência (sempre às ordens). Chama-se contínuo porque, sendo o empregado subalterno, aquele em que todos mandam, a todos obedece ato contínuo e  imediato.

Comment: Parece que na educação, já não existe: http://www.provedor-jus.pt/?action=5&idc=67&idi=2486//Data:1994-03-30

Comment: @haruki, o interrogativo é "por que" no Brasil, mas "porque" em Portugal. Se procurares, encontras uma carrada de perguntas sobre isso aqui no site.

Comment: @Lambie, talvez na linguagem administrativa oficial; na linguagem corrente continua a existir. Na universidade onde trabalho continuam a ser "contínuos".

Comment: @Diego, obrigado pelo interesse, mas eu prefiro o título original. Já agora, creio que na tua versão a palavra *contínuos* não leva aspas, já que é usada no seu sentido próprio.

Comment: @tony, a ligação entre os contínuos e a continência é interessante. Mas segundo o  Houaiss, *continência* é da família de *conter(-se)* ('autodomínio, contenção') e não de *contínuo*, que é da família de *continuar*.